# How to suppress launching beyond compare 3 while doing a comparison from windows forms application

Tags: winforms, beyondcompare3

I am using Beyond Compare 3 in my win forms application to do a comparison in two output folders (ProdOutput and SITOutput). I am using the below lines of code for doing the comparison

```
public static void LaunchViewer(string filepath1, string filepath2)
    {
        string arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", filepath1, filepath2);
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ApplicationPath, arguments);
        using (Process p = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            ComparsionResult = CompareFiles(filepath1, filepath2, BeyondCompareRules.EverythingElse);
        }
    }



public static ComparisonResult CompareFiles(string filepath1, string filepath2, string ruleName)
        {

            ComparisonResult result = ComparisonResult.None;

            string arguments = String.Format("/quickcompare /rules=\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", ruleName, filepath1, filepath2);

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ApplicationPath, arguments);
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            using (Process p = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine("EXIT [ErrorLevel]");
                p.WaitForExit();

                int exitCode = p.ExitCode;
                switch (exitCode)
                {
                    case 0:
                        result = ComparisonResult.Match;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        result = ComparisonResult.Similar;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        result = ComparisonResult.DoNotMatch;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        result = ComparisonResult.ComparisonError;
                        break;
                    default :
                        result = ComparisonResult.DoNotMatch;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Beyond compare rules are below

```
public sealed class BeyondCompareRules
{

    private BeyondCompareRules()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A comparison rule set for C/C++/C# source files
    /// </summary>
    public const string CLanguageSource = "C/C++/C# Source";
    public const string Cobol = "COBOL";
    public const string CommaSeparatedValues = "Comma Separated Values";
    public const string DelphiSource = "Delphi Source";
    public const string DelphiForms = "Delphi Forms";
    public const string GeneralText = "General Text";
    public const string Html = "HTML";
    public const string Java = "JAVA";
    public const string Python = "Python";
    public const string RegistryDump = "Registry Dump";
    public const string Utf8Text = "UTF8 Text";
    public const string VisualBasic = "Visual Basic";
    public const string Xml = "XML";

    /// <summary>
    /// The default set of comparison rules
    /// </summary>
    public const string EverythingElse = "Everything Else";

}
```

and comparisonresult is an enum as below

```
public enum ComparisonResult
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates a null or uninitialized value
    /// </summary>
    None = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Quick Compare returned a Positive Match
    /// </summary>
    Match = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Quick Compare detected small differences
    /// </summary>
    Similar = 2,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Quick Compare detected significant differences
    /// </summary>
    DoNotMatch = 3,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Quick Compare utility returned an error/unknown result
    /// </summary>
    ComparisonError = 4
}
```

What I need is to suppress launching the beyond compare screen when doing the comparison but the comparison should happen and it should return result. Now with my above code I am able to do the comparison and also able to view the differences which I don't want to do.

I guess there is some thing which I can do with passing arguments but not sure what is it and how and where should I put it.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the [command line reference](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?command_line_reference.html)?

Comment: Yes I did but I wanted to know how can I suppress the view and perform the comparison tasks. @BJMyers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several trials with different ways to achieve the functionality, finally a small piece of code did resolved the issue.

There is a command line switches available for beyond compare application which needs to be passed when we want to suppress the interactions. It is called "/silent".

I have passed along with these lines in **CompareFiles** method

*public static ComparisonResult CompareFiles(string filepath1, string filepath2, string ruleName)*

```
ComparisonResult result = ComparisonResult.None;
string arguments = String.Format("/quickcompare /rules=\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" /silent", ruleName, filepath1, filepath2);
```

All the above posted code in my question is working fine and can be used by any one who wants to suppress the interactions.